# Windows, how to convert batch program output of bytes to KB, MB or GB?

Tags: windows, batch

In windows batch, How to convert Bytes to KB or MB or GB?
In batch, How to output results to screen?

Below is a Windows batch that outputs a folder size in bytes.
example:
**2,041,737,167**  bytes in d:\temp

```
@echo off    
set bytes=    
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4" %%a in (`dir /s/w/c "d:\temp\" ^| findstr "File(s)"`) do set bytes=%%c    
echo %bytes%  bytes in d:\temp\*.*    
pause
```

In batch, how to convert?
**2,041,737,167 bytes** to:

**1,993,883 KB**   (2,041,737,167 / 1024)
**1947 MB** (2,041,737,167 / 1048576)
**1.9 GB** (2,041,737,167 / 1073741824)

--

Comment: [Math in NT batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php) - see the Workarounds: 32-bit section

Comment: I have a post here on SO with some method you could incorporate into your batch scripts using dynamic PowerShell but it's still pure batch just utilizing a PS to accommodate for the batch limitation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729893/bat-file-show-results-file-size-in-mb-instead-of-bytes/42732932#42732932.... There are other answer on that post as well you may find helpful, worth a read I suppose as you never know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the arithmetic, you need to get rid of the thousand separators first. So, change `dir /s/w/c` to `dir /s/w/-c`.
Then, it's a simple division:

```
set /a kb=%bytes% / 1024
set /a mb=%bytes% / 1048576
set /a gb=%bytes% / 1073741824
echo %kb% kB
echo %mb% MB
echo %gb% GB
```

Note that numbers are limited to 32 bits of precision, so for large folders this will fail. Also, as Yorik mentioned, numbers will be truncated.

Output will not have thousand separators. If you want that, it's probably a whole new question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Batch doesn't support floating point as far as I know, so your results will be truncated:

```
@echo off
set /a "_number=2041737167/1073741824"
echo %_number%
pause
```

Would emit `1` instead of `1.9`

Often, people will call cscript (etc) for math functions (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503888/floating-point-division-in-a-dos-batch )

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.exe` is a 32 bits process so commands as:

```
set /a result1=%bytes% / 1024
```

will fail with the error: **"Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision**

If you happen to be in a 64 bit device (nowadays it's very likely), call the command prompt from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` and it will work, for example you command line should be something like this:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /C path\to\batchfile.cmd
```

Comment: I don't see much luck with syswow's cmd.. https://i.imgur.com/WReB1cs.png